# How long does it take before a web page is saved in Google Cache?

Tags: google-search

I've heard a lot of people asking how long information stays in Google Cache. To me, this is irrelevant (at least until someone libels my name).

Comment: This should be closed as Not-programming-related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is probably not a good answer, or at least there is probably not a good answer that you will get outside of Googleplex.

For Google to crawl and cache your page, usually someone has to link to you, or you have to request they crawl your site.

You can influence how frequently it visits your site by setting up a [sitemap](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=40318&topic=13450), but as far as I know Google doesn't make any guarantees anywhere that it will crawl your site on any particular schedule.

Answer (score 5):

It depends. Google visits frequent-changing pages more often than static sites. And if google doesn't know your site exists, how can it then visit (and cache) your site?

If you're site are hosted on a new and unknown webadress, you should tell google to visit you. Or you can drop a lot of links to you site all over the web.

If you have created a new article on your current cached site, google will find out in a day or two. Or maybe a lot quicker. (But you do need  link pointing towards that new article.) As I said: it all depends ;)

Tip: You probably have access to a site-log, which will tell you how often googlebot browses your site!

Answer (score 3):

Google cache exists until google removes it due to 404 errors, 302 location redirects, or specific expire meta headers (noindex, nosnippet, noarchive) on the next crawling. It is also possible to remove links from google manually.

Caching: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35306&ctx=sibling
Removing: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35301

Answer (score 0):

Well, a page is saved in Google cache for ever :-)

And I think it is saved in Google cache when it has been crawled.

Comment: So naturally, my next question is: How long does it take for Google to crawl a page?

Comment: That is not a good question... it will vary significantly depending on how linked your site is.  I could say 15 minutes or I could say 2 weeks and both would be a right answer...

Comment: Google crawls pages in less than twelve parsecs.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can probably do on your side of things is to set appropriate cache control HTTP headers and hope Google pays attention to them.